# Task :app:checkProdDebugAarMetadata FAILED

Tags: react-native, apple-m1, yarn-workspaces

React native is not installing application. I tried gradlew clean but it didn't solve the problem.
[image]

Comment: Decrease the minSDK to 30.

Comment: @MichaelBahl minSdkVersion is 21

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is because of `androidx.core` latest release. Check [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/versions).

Make the following change in `android/build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        androidXCore = "1.6.0" // <-----    Add this line
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 30
        targetSdkVersion = 29
        ndkVersion = "20.1.5948944"
    }
}
```